# Transform multiple variables and save them with new names

Tags: r

Imagine I want to take logs of the following variables in the `mtcars` data set: `disp`, `wt` and `drat`. I would like to save them as `log_disp`, `log_wt` and `log_wt`.

I can take the logs for all and save it with:

```
cols <- c("disp","wt","drat")
mtcars[cols] <- log(mtcars[cols])
```

However, this overwrites the initial variable, which I would like to keep. How could I transform and save as a new variable simultaneously?

Comment: `mtcars[paste0("log_", cols)] <- log(mtcars[cols])`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I was thinking on some dynamic apply... but your solution is neater and probably also faster!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just append to the names in the assignment:

```
mtcars[paste("log",cols,sep="_")] <- log(mtcars[cols])
```

Answer (score 3):

I really like the base R way propesed by James & David. There's also a relatively simple dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_at(mtcars, setNames(cols, paste0("log_", cols)), log)
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb log_disp    log_wt log_drat
#1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 5.075174 0.9631743 1.360977
#2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 5.075174 1.0560527 1.360977
#3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 4.682131 0.8415672 1.348073
```

Since `setNames(cols, paste0("log_", cols))` creates a named vector, the new columns are added to the result instead of modifying existing columns.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse` to make this more dynamic

```
library(tidyverse)
f1 <- function(data, columns){
 data %>%
      transmute_at(columns, log) %>%
      rename_all(funs(paste("log", columns, sep="_"))) %>%
      bind_cols(data, .)

 }

res <- f1(mtcars, cols)
head(res, 3)
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb log_disp    log_wt log_drat
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 5.075174 0.9631743 1.360977
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 5.075174 1.0560527 1.360977
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 4.682131 0.8415672 1.348073
```

---

Or change the function using `mutate_at`

```
f2 <- function(data, columns){
data %>%
       mutate_at(columns, funs(log = log(.))) %>%
       rename_at(vars(matches('log')), funs(sub('(\\w+)_(\\w+)', "\\2_\\1", .)))
}
f2(mtcars, cols)
```

NOTE: Both the `dplyr` solutions use standard `dplyr` syntax